# Get substring with first N words

Tags: javascript, string

I have the unicode-based text and I need to get symbols count of the first N (let's say 500-1000-1500) words

I need to keep all symbols (so if where the string is

`"a   b"`

the result should be 5)

My idea is to match first N-words using some regular expression and then get the length (count of symbols) of the match result.

Maybe something like

```
text.match(/([^\s]+\s+){500}/)
```

But it sucks when it comes to punctuation signs

Actually, I came out with this idea. What do you guys think about it?

```
text.match(/(\w+\s*[^\s\w]*\s+){5}/)
```

Comment: get rid of punctuation symbols first?

Comment: how big is your string? if you can afford calling split(" ") on it you can then remove seeds from blackberries

Comment: string can be any size (and it will be 200-20 000 words long)

Comment: Why would "a b" be 5? Wouldn't it be 3?

Comment: sorry, editor removed multi spaces between a and b. will update now

Comment: 20K words might limit you on the approach. You may want to look at ES6 iterators, if you can use them.

Comment: Thanks for giving me direction =)

Answer (score 1):

Would this sort of thing work for you?

```js
const words = text.split(' ').slice(0, 500)
const symbolCount = words.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.length + 1, -1)
```

Split the text at spaces then loop through and accumulate the character counts.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear while asking. I need to keep all symbols (so if where the string is "a   b" it should be 5

Comment: Thank you. But I think it wont work, as text can be "hello + three spaces + . + hello1"

Comment: @AmeliaSeila I'm pretty sure this would work. It gives you the length including all spaces. I think you should try the example before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: @BrandonDyer, sorry, but it does not ;(

string: "hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4 . hello5 hello6 hello7 hello8", 
words count: 5,
result: 29,
expected: 36

Comment: @AmeliaSeila It does work. I tested it. The result of `"hello1 hello2 hello3 hello4 . hello5 hello6 hello7 hello8"` is 57 as expected

Comment: sorry, maybe I was not clear in my question. I need to get length of first N words (I tested your response using example string and tried to get length of first 5 words)

Comment: anyway, I'm happy to thank you for your response =)

Answer (score 0):

Try making it so the string has only words when you run the match

```js
text
  .replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]/gi,'')
  .match(/([^\s]+\s+){500}/)
```

Comment: sorry, I was not clear while asking. I need to keep all symbols (so if where the string is "a + three spaces + b" it should be 5